# How can I create and maintain sessions in series of Perl CGI scripts?

Tags: perl, apache, session, cgi

I am new to CGI-Perl and sessions. I have a problem running the following code.

I have four files
1. Session.html or Session.pm
2. name.pl
3. hobbies.pl
4. job.pl

The Session.pm is place in /var/www/html folder and the rest of the files are placed in /var/www/cgi-bin/session folder.

***I have a basic html file(Session.html) which has a link to perl script it is giving the following error***

```
[Mon Jan 04 14:21:24 2010] [error] [client ::1] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /var/www/html/name.pl, referer: http://localhost/Session.html
[Mon Jan 04 14:21:29 2010] [error] [client ::1] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /var/www/html/name.pl, referer: http://localhost/Session.html
[Mon Jan 04 14:22:42 2010] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/session/name.pl' failed, referer: http://localhost/Session.pm
[Mon Jan 04 14:22:42 2010] [error] [client ::1] Premature end of script headers: name.pl, referer: http://localhost/Session.pm
```

Please help me out in executing the above example. Please give me the steps to be followed from the start.

Comment: Instead of showing the 500 server error from your browser you could check the error log file (located, well, where your Apache stores error logs) and post the error log entry for your request.
It usually points out to where the problem occured.

Answer (score 4):

> ... Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /var/www/html/name.pl, ...

This error points to trying to run `name.pl` in /var/www/html/ instead of /var/www/cgi-bin/session/

Is the Session.html you posted correct because it doesn't seem to tally with this error?

> ... (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/session/name.pl' failed, ...

The `name.pl` cannot be run because it doesn't have execution rights set (on Linux/Unix you need to `chmod a+x name.pl`).

You may need to show what Session.pm does (it doesn't look like you using the CPAN module [`Session`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Session/) here).

On a general note I would consider simplifying what you doing down to a simple HTML & CGI script first and get that working.  Then start looking into sessions etc.

Check out [Ovid's CGI Tutorial](http://jdporter.perlmonk.org/cgi_course/) for some sage advice on the Perl/CGI subject.

/I3az/